# How to install Ulteo Open Virtual Desktop on Ubuntu 13.10?

Tags: software-installation

Has anyone installed Ulteo Open Virtual Desktop on Ubuntu 13.10? I cannot locate a .deb or a compressed (tar, zip) file containing the binaries.

Answer (score 0):

Ulteo Open Virtual Desktop v3.0 can be installed as given in [its installation guide page](http://doc.ulteo.com/3.0/Support_Ubuntu_Lucid.html) of its website.

Answer (score 0):

The below steps were taken [this page](http://doc.ulteo.com/latest/Easy_Installation.html#sm), with slight modification.

1. Add the Ulteo repository to the repository list:

   ```
   sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://archive.ulteo.com/ovd/3.0/ubuntu lucid main" >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/01-ulteo-ovd.list'
   sudo apt-get update
   ```

   > **[Note]**
   >   GPG errors given by the previous command will be fixed in
   >   the next installation steps. They won't prevent the installation to be
   >   successful.
2. Install the keyring package to validate the repository using gpg:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ulteo-keyring
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. Install the ulteo-ovd-debconf-database package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ulteo-ovd-debconf-database
   ```
4. Install the ulteo-ovd-easy-install package:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ulteo-ovd-easy-install
   ```

   > **[Important]**
   >   Do not install both ulteo-ovd-easy-install and ulteo-ovd-debconf-database in the same command line or your install
   >   will fail.

   > **[Note]**
   >   This installation can take some minutes. As default, it automatically download the Ulteo OVD susbsystem from ulteo.com, it's a
   >   600MB file.
5. Once done, you just have to restart the service:

   ```
   sudo /etc/init.d/ulteo-ovd-subsystem restart
   ```

Source:  http://doc.ulteo.com/latest/Easy_Installation.html#sm